# Does the series $\sum_{ n = 0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ln\bigl(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\bigr)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{ n = 0}^{\infty } U_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ 
I was trying to resolve it by any method convergence, but I could not show if the series converges or diverges.

Comment: Hint: Note that this converges if and only if the sequence with $\sqrt{n}$ replaced by $n$ converges.

Comment: Are you talking about a series or  a sequence? The sequence $\{U_n\}$ is convergent but the series $\sum \{U_n\}$ is divergent.

Comment: i am talking about a serie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is a series with positive terms, the simplest is to use *equivalents* (by limits comparison test):

We know that $\;\ln(1+x)\sim_0 x$, so we deduce an  equivalent for the general term of this series:
$$\frac1{\sqrt n}\,\log\Bigl(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\Bigr)\sim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt n}\,\frac1{\sqrt n}=\frac 1n,$$
which is the general term of the (divergent) harmonic series.

Comment: By limit comparison test, it should be added.

Comment: @gimusi: Done, mylord!

Comment: That’s perfect now! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Compare with $\sum \frac 1 n$. The series is divergent. Hint: $\log (1+x) \geq \frac 1 2 x$ for $x>0$ and sufficiently small.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac1{\sqrt n}\log \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)\sim \frac1{\sqrt n}\frac1{\sqrt n} =\frac1n$$

then refer to limit comparison test.

Comment: can you explain it ? i don't understand

Comment: Recall that as $x\to 0$ we have $\log(1+x)\sim x$ therefore $$\frac1{\sqrt n}\log \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)\sim \frac1{\sqrt n}\frac1{\sqrt n} =\frac1n$$

Comment: Do you know limit comparison test?

Comment: You can find a reference here [LCT](https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf) and note that it is necessary refer to it for a rigorous proof.